# Why is Apache not respecting aliased directories?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-httpd, alias, proxy

In `ssl_default.conf` where Apache serves as an SSL-adding proxy for Django Gunicorn, I have:

```
    ...
    Alias /admin/static/ "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/"

    ProxyPass /media/ !
    ProxyPass /admin/static/ !
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
```

What should I be doing differently to have `/admin/static/*` serving up the contents of the URL above? At present it appears to be handing requests, including `/admin/static/*`, to the Django Gunicorn process.

**UPDATE**

Now I'm getting a 403 after expanding:

```
    Alias /admin/static/ "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/"
    <Directory "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>
```

This is on attempting to access `/admin/static/css/base.css`.

Suggestions?

Comment: Check your `error.log`. It may be possible that the alias overlaps and therefore will never match; look for errors like `The Alias directive in ... at line ... will probably never match because it overlaps an earlier Alias.`

Comment: I didn't see anything current in the error log; and Apache from the UI is not reporting an error, just handing the request to Django as would be appropriate if I weren't trying to alias a directory.

Comment: Could it be the trailing slash? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13189261/apache2-alias-not-working-in-ubuntu

Comment: I'm not saying that I shouldn't change that, but I have only attempted to see it by adding a trailing slash. That is, I haven't attempted to access /admin/static, only /admin/static/*.

Comment: Breadcrumb note: I wrong "controb" for "contrib" in the Directory tab. However, fixing that did not seem to solve the problem.